# C# Http Proxy ideas?

Tags: c#, http, proxy

I need a system which redirects connection requests from client machines to different sites i.e. if they type google.com they should be redirected to mysite.com

Therefore I thought of creating an app that installs a proxy on user's machines so that the app could check their outgoing connections and redirect accordingly.

Are there any open source HTTP proxies available on the net? I have tried Mentalis but that seems to be quite buggy now that it is around 8 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this one](http://www.hottproxy.org/) will help you.

I haven't tested it myself, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

If your redirects are simple and at the domain level, it's probably simpler to configure a DNS server for the clients.

Another alternative is to configure up any of the various proxy servers already available for various platforms, instead of a local proxy on each client. [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org) is very flexible and performant (although it runs on Linux/FreeBSD only).

If your clients are distributed and you can't point them all to the same proxy or DNS, then you should try the local proxy approach (but this starts looking very much like a virus)

Code samples:

http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs
http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/psingh/WebServer04162005083342AM/WebServer.aspx